# Could not send request Postman

Tags: postman

tengo este mensaje cuando intento ejecutar postman:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto tengo en settings:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto obtengo cuando ejecuto 'ping apirestfulescuelait.dev' en mi consola de comando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No tienes acceso al recurso, verifica que el mismo está disponible. Por otro lado te invito a repasar [ask]. Tu pregunta no parece adecuada para el sitio tal como lo plantea el [help/on-topic]. Saludos

Comment: como hago para tener acceso al recurso?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes dar algo más de información?
Qué se pretende conseguir al ejecutar la request?
Esa URL no te hace ni ping, no existe. No puede devolver nada si ni siquiera existe.